# Issue on make the code compliant for sonar rule S1451 for C#

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am using the sonar (v5.6.6) and c# plugin (v6.3)for code analysis.  After sonar analysis execution. My [C# Code](https://github.com/vival30/Sample/blob/master/Program.cs) violated rule [**S1451**](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/blob/master/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/rspec/cs/S1451_c%23.html) (Rule Name: **Track lack of copyright and license headers**).

I tried many of the copyright formats, but no luck all fails to compliant with this rule.

How to make the code to compliant with rule S1451?

Answer (score 1):

[S1451](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarcsharp/rules.html#RSPEC-1451) is configured with the required/desired header. The easiest thing to do would be to look at the configuration of the rule in the profile that's being applied & copy/paste the configured header into your file.

Comment: Thanks for your support Ann, but i tried [**this**](https://github.com/vival30/Sample/blob/master/Program1.cs) & added the license txt file in solution level & project level, but no luck its also fails to compliant with the rule **S1451**.

Answer (score 0):

this issue was resolved by Amaury Levé from SonarSource team.

Please check this [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/sonarqube/00a02b60-a865-40d0-a78d-fee86e705916%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer) for more details.

Thanks a lot to Amaury & sonar team...